# How to use img src tag with php for WordPress theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, image, themes, src

I'm working on my first WordPress Theme and I have a problem with the `img src` tag inside my `.php` file. It shows me that the image src is `unknown`. How do I solve this problem?

This is my code:

```
<h1>General</h1>
<?php settings_errors(); ?>
<?php $mplogo = esc_attr(get_Option( 'mp_logo' ));?>
<?php echo '<img src="' . $mp_logo . '">'; ?>

/* SAVE THE FIELDS
<form method="post" action="options.php">
  <?php settings_fields('maikpro-settings-group'); ?>
  <?php do_settings_sections('mp_maikpro') ?>
  <?php submit_button(); ?>
</form>
```

Comment: For starters, `get_Option` should be `get_option`.

Comment: Also, what does `<?php print_r( $mplogo ); ?>` show?

Comment: There isn't enough info in this question to get you a proper answer. Try to include what the input of `$mp_logo` (your expected output) is and an echo of `$mp_logo` to show it's current value at the time you are trying to output it. As a pure guess I expect that your `get_option` return value is an array when you expect a string.

Comment: @WilliamPatton I want to upload a logo with the wordpress mediauploader. The uploader works. But If I want to see a preview of my uploaded picture the img src is unknown.

Comment: @cabrerahector <?php print_r( $mplogo ); ?> shows nothing. :(

Comment: William might be onto something here. Try `<?php print_r( get_option( 'mp_logo' ) ); ?>` and report back.